# Makefile doesn't find source files

Tags: makefile

I have tried to make a makefile. I have the following folder structure.

```
Source
  - include
     - My headerfiles
  - objects
     - The object files
  - src
     - My source files
```

My problem is that the source files in the src directory isn't found.

My make file looks as the following.

```
# gcc for C
# g++ for c++
CC = gcc

#compiler flags
# -g adds debugging information to the executebells
# -Wall
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

#target
TARGET = gabe_the_dog_server
#directory for the object files
OBJDIR = ./objects
SRCDIR = ./src

default: $(TARGET)
all: default

HEADERS = $(wildcard include/*.h)
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $(OBJDIR)/$@

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    -rm -f *.o
    -rm -f $(TARGET)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
```

You use the variable `SOURCES`, but you never define it. You need one more line:

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the path to your source files, it's recommended that you put this path in the special variable named `VPATH`. Then you just mention your source file, like this:

```
OBJDIR = ./obj
SRCDIR = ./src
VPATH = $(SRCDIR)
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, foo.o bar.o)

all: $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
$(cc) ...
```

GNU `make` will look in the folders present in `VPATH` for the files that are prerequisites of a target. Note that this could be a problem if you have multiple folders where you can find multiple times the same file name.

See [GNU make VPATH manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html). If you need additional examples of VPATH good practices, see this link as well: [Mad Scientist: How not to use VPATH](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/how-not-to-use-vpath/)